# When I add-migration, update-database for a FavoriteGames db and a Games db, only the table for Games is created. Favorites is a child of Game class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-migrations, webapi

I have a Game class and a child class Favorite with the same properties inside. I want the Favorite class to be of type Game so that I can add a Game to the Favorites database thats why I cannot create a different type.

I have a working Game class with a GameApi , GameRepo, and a
public DbSet Games { get; set; }
in the DataContext, also everything else required in the program.cs etc. and I continued step-by-step from there.

from the start until the last step the same problem remains and a Favorites table isn't created with the migration and also when I create it manually the POST of the FavoriteApi isn't working

-added a
public DbSet Favorites { get; set; }
and also added similar functions for post and get in the GameRepo and GameApi only changing the target to Favorites db.

-next I created a child class
public class Favorite: Game
without declaring the properties inside as they are declared in the base class and keeping the above.

-after that I created FavoriteRepo and FavoriteApi and moved the related functions there also added the required things in the program.cs etc.

-next I copy-pasted the same properties from the Game class inside Favorite class

Comment: You shouldn't use inheritance but you should make `Favorite` have a `Game` member variable

Comment: oh but then the instances of Favorite would be of type Object:Favorite and not Game, and I wont be able to add objects from one database to another

Comment: Instances of Favorite would have a member variable `Game` and adding objects would be done via a join table. Also, an even more simple approach would be to just have `Favorite` be a boolean field in the Game class

Comment: I hadn't thought of the second approach, Im gonna implement this. Thank you

Comment: Great! can you accept the answer below?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instances of Favorite would have a member variable Game and adding objects would be done via a join table. Also, an even more simple approach would be to just have Favorite be a boolean field in the Game class